# Python variable range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to have a range that I can change on the fly. What I have found here didn't help me to fix my error.

I am currently using a fixed variable to test what I am doing

I can not figure out how to post the actual code; I can't get it to paste. So this is the general idea (I made this run; it fails with variables but works with numbers).

I am using anaconda3 in Spyder (python 3.5).

```
hi = 20
hf = 0
step = .1
H = np.arange(hi, hf, step) ####range(start,end,step)
U = []
for l in H:
    U.append(l)

print(U)
>>> []
```

I tried using `float` and `int` both when defining the variables (in every way) and inside the `range()`. I tried a few other things as well. But the only way I can get anything but an empty `[]` being printed is by using numbers (any type of number works).

Comment: Have you checked `H`? It's probably empty, since your start `hi` is larger than the end `hf`, but `step` is positive.

Answer (score 0):

Running exactly this code:

```
import numpy
U=[]
H=numpy.arange(0, 20, 0.1)
for l in H:
    U.append(l)
print(U)
```

works exactly as you'd expect. The problem is that you're trying to run with bounds switched around - with your constants the call is actually `arange(20, 0, 0.1)`

Answer (score -1):

```
def drange(start, stop, step):
    r = start
    while r < stop:
        yield r
        r += step

i0=drange(0.0, 1.0, 0.1)
print(["%g" % x for x in i0])
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation along with your code.